# what does "for being so" mean here?

Tags: conjunctions

Amidst the callousness and exploitation, moments of compassion are few and far between, although perhaps all the more significant **for being so rare**.

"**because they** (moments of compassion) **are so rare**".

I am wondering what is the difference between the bold part semantically or emotionally? What do you feel when it comes to differentiating?

Thanks

...........................

Excerpted from the answer that Damkerng T.(a member of this forum) has just provided.

And , the link is the following:
[enter link description here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59218/what-does-all-the-more-significant-for-being-so-rare-mean)

Answer (score 1):

I am not a native speaker, but:

There is no difference in meaning between the two sentences.
The subclause *for being so rare* is what we call *non-finite*. This means that it contains a non-finite verb (infinitive, participle or gerund). Non-finite clauses typically do not have a subject, but refer to a word outside the non-finite clause, in this case *moments of compassion*. There are also no tenses in non-finite clauses.

However, this type of clause can easily be rewritten to a finite clause (at least in this case it can), just as you have done:

> ...because they (*moments of compassion*) are so rare.

Note that the finite subclause contains more words than the non-finite one while it expresses the same meaning. Clauses can often be rewritten to non-finite clauses to make your text shorter and easier to read.